# How to solve heat equation on the semi-infinite rod by Fourier Transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, heat-equation

**Question**

Solve the following heat equation on the semi-infinite rod by Fourier Transform
$$u_t=ku_{xx}$$ where $x,t>0$ and
$u_x(0,t) =0$ and $u(x,0)=\begin{cases} 
      1, & 0 < x <2 \\
      0, &  2\leq x  
   \end{cases}
$

**My attempt**

If we apply Fourier Trans. to both sides, we get

$ \frac{\partial \mathcal{F} \{U(w,t)\}}{\partial t} = -kw^{2} \mathcal{F} \{U(w,t)\}$

Solving the ODE, we have
$U(w,t)=C(w)e^{-kw^2t}$

to find $C(w)$ we use the initial condt. $u(x,0)$

$C(w)=\mathcal{F} \{u(x,0)\}=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x,0) e^{-iwx} \ dx $

**Could you help me to solve the rest? What is the solution $$u\left(x,t\right)=\mathrm{TF}^{-1}\{U(w,t)\}=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}}\intop_{x\in\mathbb{R}}C(w)e^{-kw^2t}e^{iwx}dw$$?**

(I can't calculate $C(w)$ since $u(x,0)$ is undefined on $-\infty<x<0$ )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve Heat Equation using Fourier Transform (non homogeneous)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150642/solve-heat-equation-using-fourier-transform-non-homogeneous)

Comment: No, it is not fully duplicate. $u(x,0)$ is piecewise function in here. I can' t solve the question.

Comment: And what is the problem just plugging your piecewise  function in the given solution.

Comment: How is $u(x,0)$ define for $x<0$ your function is missing something check your exercise once more

Comment: There is no missing something. That is all. May be somebody will solve the question. So, we will learn how to solve.

Comment: Then u(x,0) is not a function since it does not value for x<0

Comment: See the answer below you understand what I meant

Comment: Thank you. Can the problem be solved by Fourier-cosine or Fourier-sine Transform? Because the integral  from $x=0$  to $x=\infty$ in the transforms.

Comment: yes it can be solve with all of that as long as $u_0$ is define for x<0

Comment: The question aren't created by me. A professor ask the us in the Calculus of variation class.

Comment: Did your professor asked to use that Fourier Transform? because this will wounder me

Comment: Yes, he said to solve it by proper Fourier transform.

Comment: @GuyFsone I think this question is indeed a duplicate of the question you linked (calculating Fourier cosine transform of a piecewise function is trivial), but that question hasn't been correctly answered so far. I've posted an answer there, have a look.

Comment: @GuyFsone BTW I'd like to point out OP has actually asked this question twice…: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2467847/58219

Comment: the point is not getting A solution  .  the op asked a  solution using fourrier transforms. and my answer show that it is not possible via fourrier transforms

Comment: @GuyFsone To be precise, OP is asking whether the problem can be solved with [**proper** Fourier transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473201/how-to-solve-heat-equation-on-the-semi-infinite-rod-by-fourier-transform/2476391#comment5110285_2473201). :) One can argue that _Fourier transform_ can't be used as a general name of _complex Fourier transform_, _Fourier sine transfrom_, _Fourier cosine transform_, etc. though.

Comment: From a computational perspective, the Fourier cosine and Fourier sine transforms can be implemented by reflecting (+flipping) functions on [0,∞), then applying the ordinary Fourier transform, so I suspect this may have been why a 'proper' Fourier transform was mentioned in the question. More generally, you need to transform to a space that diagonalizes the diffusion operator on [0,∞). The Fourier cosine/sine transforms will work. See this answer for more depth: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1903869/223565

Answer (score 1):

Let $u_0(x) =u(x,0)$ then 
$$C(w)=\mathcal{F} \{u_0\}(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x,0) e^{-iwx} \ dx$$
We also know the following
$$ e^{-kw^2t} = \mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2kt}} \displaystyle{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4kt}}}\right)(w)$$

Whence it follows that, 
$$U(w,t)= C(w)e^{-kw^2t}=\mathcal{F} \{u_0\}(w)\cdot\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2kt}} \displaystyle{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4kt}}}\right)(w)$$

[Using the product rule for Fourier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) we have 
$$u\left(x,t\right)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{U(w,t)\} =\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{\mathcal{F} \{u_0\}\cdot\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2kt}} \displaystyle{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4kt}}}\right)\right\}\\= u_0\star\frac{1}{\sqrt{2kt}} \displaystyle{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4kt}}}~~~\text{convolution }\\=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2kt}}\int_\Bbb R u_0(y)e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}}dy 
\\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2kt}}\int_{2}^{\infty} \underbrace{u_0(y)}_{0}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}}dy
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2kt}}\int_{0}^{2} \underbrace{u_0(y)}_{1}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}}dy \\+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2kt}}\int_{-\infty}^{2}\underbrace{u_0(y)}_{?}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^0}{4kt}}dy\\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2kt}}\int_{0}^{2} e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}}dy +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2kt}}\int_{-\infty}^{2}\underbrace{u_0(y)}_{?-u_0~~is ~~not~~define}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^0}{4kt}}dy $$

YOU HAVE TO DEIFNE $u_0$ FOR $x<0$

Answer (score 1):

The separated solutions $X(x)T(t)$ must solve
$$
        \frac{T'(t)}{kT(t)} = -\lambda = \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)},\;\; X'(0)=0.
$$
The solutions have the form $T(t)=Ce^{-\lambda t}$, $X(x)=D\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$, and $\lambda > 0$ is natural in order to have boundedness in time and space of the separated solutions. Letting $\lambda=s^2$ gives a trial solution
$$
                u(x,t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}F(s)e^{-s^2t}\cos(sx)ds.
$$
In order to satisfy the condition on $u(x,0)$, it is necessarily to determine a coefficient function $F$ such that
$$
          \int_{0}^{\infty}F(s)\cos(sx)ds=\chi_{[0,2]}(x),
$$
which is solved by the inverse Fourier cosine transform:
\begin{align}
  F(s) & = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\chi_{[0,2]}(x)\cos(sx)dx \\
       & = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\sin(sx)dx= -\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\cos(2s)-1}{s}.
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
           u(x,t) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-s^2 t}\frac{1-\cos(2s)}{s}\cos(sx)ds.
$$